# Is there an equivalent to DataFrame.idxmax for when the DataFrame contains a string?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm using pandas to read a simple CSV file of election results:

```
constituency,anug,apnuafc,cg,ljp,pppc,...
Barima-Waini,0,3905,0,170,8022,...
Pomeroon-Supenaam,86,7343,149,120,18788,...
Essequibo Islands-West Demerara,310,23811,318,0,47855,...
...
```

I access this with `election.votes` in `views.py`:

```
results = pd.read_csv(election.votes)
```

For each row I want to add a new column for the winning party. I've tried:

```
results["winner"] = results.max(axis=1)
```

But this adds the highest *value*, not the corresponding column header. So I've tried:

```
results["winner"] = results.idxmax(axis=1)
```

I then get the error `reduction operation 'argmax' not allowed for this dtype`.

Because of the strings of the constituencies I can't use `to_numeric` to make `idxmax` work.

Is there another efficient way to get the column header?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.select_dtypes`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.select_dtypes.html) for get only numeric columns:

```
import numpy as np

results["winner"] = results.select_dtypes(np.number).idxmax(axis=1)
```

Comment: Goodness. That was very fast and very useful. When using `np.number` I get the `name 'np' is not defined` error, so I used `results["winner"] = results.select_dtypes("number").idxmax(axis=1)` instead. I'm not familiar enough with pandas and did not know `select_dtypes`, thank you so much!